A graph with radius of curvature $≥1$ can't have more than 2 distinct real intersection points with a circle of radius 1
Is the following true?

If the graph of a continuously twice differentiable function $y(x)$ and the radius of curvature $|\frac1\kappa |$ is $\gt 1$ at all points on the graph (e.g. $y=\sin(x),x\in(0,\frac\pi2)$), then it can't have more than $2$ distinct real intersection points with a circle of radius $1$.


Related:

How the curvature of a curve affects its behavior relative to a circle
What is the largest circle that fits in $\sin(x)?$
how to prove that the curvature of sin x is greatest at its extremum?

I have a rough idea:
From curvature formula for a graph: $$\kappa =\frac{y''}{\left(1+y'^{\,2}\right)^{\frac {3}{2}}}$$
so$$\int\kappa~\mathrm{d}s =\int\frac{y''(x)}{\left(1+y'(x)^2\right)^{\frac {3}{2}}}~\mathrm{d}s=\int\frac{y''(x)}{\left(1+y'(x)^2\right)}~\mathrm{d}x=\arctan y'(x)$$
so, if $s$ is arc-length parameter and there is smooth function $\phi$ such that $(\cos\phi(s),\sin\phi(s))$ is the unit tangent vector, then $\int_{s_0}^{s_1}\kappa~\mathrm{d}s=\phi(s_1)-\phi(s_0)$
If the graph intersects a circle of radius $1$ at three points $A,B,C$, and the graph is lower than the circle between $A,B$ and the graph is higher than the circle between $B,C$, then $\phi$ of the graph at $A$ is less than $\phi$ of the circle at $A$, but $\phi$ of the graph at $B$ is greater than $\phi$ of the circle at $B$, so $\phi(s_B)-\phi(s_A)$ is greater than that of the circle, so the integral of $κ$ from $A$ to $B$ is greater than that of the circle, but $κ$ of the graph is assumed to be less than than curvature $1$ of the circle, contradiction.


I think your idea should work, you just need to formalise it a bit.

You need twice-differentiable in order for the radius of curvature to even be defined. But $y = \sqrt{1-x^2}$ for $x \in (-1,1)$ is continuously differentiable and has radius of curvature $\ge 1$ and uncountably many points of intersection with a circle of radius $1$. Now if you were to specify a radius of curvature $> 1$, then you might be right.

@PaulSinclair Thanks! I changed it to $>1$.
